# Can't use a YAML parameter type step

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

**My issue**

I am testing this YAML script in Azure DevOps:

```
parameters:
  - name: myStep
    type: step
    default:
      script: echo my step

  - name: mySteplist
    type: stepList
    default:
      - script: echo step one
      - script: echo step two
   
jobs: 
  - job: myStep
    steps:
      - ${{ parameters.myStep }}
  - job: stepList
    steps: ${{ parameters.mySteplist }}
```

But lines with `${{ }}` are rejected with this error message:

> Incorrect type. Expected "object"

**What I need**

Why am I getting this message? What can I do to fix it?

**What I tested**

I found this sample in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops). This is what puzzle me. I would expect this to be a valid YAML script given the source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it was confirmed to be due to a bug in Visual Studio Code, and not actually related to either the script or to Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

I found what happend.

This is a bug in Visual Studio Code. The script works as expected when launch